# Get Image height & width using file input and JQuery?

Tags: jquery, image

I'm uploading an image using file input control. I would like to validate the height-width of it before upload. Is there any way to do it using JQuery? How?

Comment: Check Filereader API.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this get the image id and use this function:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

your question is same as this: 
[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)